# Erlang argument matching and performance

Tags: performance, erlang, matching

Any difference between these two from a performance (or any other) perspective?

f1(X=whatever) -> ok;
(more...)

and

f2(whatever=X) -> ok;
(more...)

Comment: Why are you using assignment as a pattern matching expression?  It is very confusing.  Didn't you mean "f1() when X = whatever"?

Comment: Assignment in Erlang is effect of pattern matching with unbound variable — it's not confusing, to me at least.

Comment: The reason I use assignment in the arguments is so that I can use the assigned variable later down in the code.  The above code is too trivial to show this, but if I was matching on some complicated list or tuple, I can use the assigned variable later instead of typing in the complicated structure.  My assumption is that the engine will pattern match on the complicated structure, not the variable (which is what I want).  My question is whether this is true or not, i.e. whether the above would always match on the atom "whatever" (what I want) or whether it matches on X sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

You can examine the code the compiler produces by compiling with -S which generates a .S file.  You'll get something like this and you can confirm that the compiler generates exactly the same code for each of your two cases.

```
{function, f1, 1, 12}.
{label,11}.
{func_info,{atom,test},{atom,f1},1}.
{label,12}.
{test,is_eq_exact,{f,11},[{x,0},{atom,whatever}]}.
return.
```

Personally, I find "whatever=X" counter-intuitive and harder to read.

Comment: I do too, but interestingly I saw some of the developers using this style in their code, where as I use X=whatever, which is why I decided to ask this question (perhaps they knew more than me?).

Comment: I prefer `whatever=X`. To me `=` then behaves like it does in a body: the RHS is a variable/value and the LHS is a pattern which it matches against. It, as @cthulahoops says, makes no difference to the code generated, the LHS and RHS are *aliases*.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` in a pattern means that the LHS and RHS are *aliases* referring to the data same value. Both sides have to match the value so writing something `{X}=[Y]` will never match (and the compiler will complain). It is most often used like `{X,Y}=T` which allows you to both match and pull apart the data **and** still have a reference to the whole structure. Both to have your cake and eat it. Note that it can be used anywhere in a pattern and not just at the top level so you can use it like `{foo,[H|T]=A,B,C}`.

There is no performance difference.